# JavaScript studies. How Map() code are being executed?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Good evening.

I'm really struggling to get my head around this and I'm not sure if I'm missing something really stupid, but here is my code and my question.

```
const question = new Map();

question.set('question', 'What is the official name of the latest major JavaScript version?');
question.set(1, 'ES5');
question.set(2, 'ES6');
question.set(3, 'ES2015');
question.set(4, 'ES7');
question.set('correct', 3);
question.set(true, 'Correct answer :D');
question.set(false, 'Wrong, please try again!');

for (let [key, value] of question.entries()) {
    if (typeof(key) === 'number') {
        console.log(`Answer ${key}: ${value}`);
    }
}

const ans = parseInt(prompt('Write the correct answer'));

console.log(question.get(ans === question.get('correct')));
```

Can someone please explain to me how, when I insert the right value into the prompt box; the interpreter?... knows to check the next line of code to display "Correct" or "Wrong in the console? depending on my input. I know we have a `key of correct` and its value is set to `3` but when do we tell it to execute the next lines of code depending on my answer? Does it just parse through the whole code, see a true statement and then executes whatever it is attached too, else execute the false statement? How, why? Apologies if I'm not coming through very clearly.

Comment: I understand. I just want to know how it works though. I truly can't understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Map` has an entry for key `true` and one for `false`. One of them is retrieved by using a key that corresponds to this expression:

```
ans === question.get('correct')
```

This expression returns `true` when the given answer is equal to the correct one, and `false` otherwise. This boolean result is then used as key for the next lookup in your set:

```
question.get(ans === question.get('correct'))
```

This effectively retrieves the value for either `false` or `true` -- as stored in your Map. And so the correct phrase is retrieved (and displayed).

If you would write that magic line a bit more verbose, it could look like this:

```
let output;
if (ans === question.get('correct')) { // get() returns 3 here.
    output = question.get(true); // This retrieves 'Correct answer :D'
} else {
    output = question.get(false); // This retrieves 'Wrong, please try again!'
}
console.log(output);
```

But realise how `ans === question.get('correct')` is a boolean expression, meaning it represents `false` or `true`, exactly what you want to pass as value to `question.get` in order to retrieve the phrase to be output.

So, instead of the `if` construct you can do:

```
let isCorrect = (ans === question.get('correct')); // false or true 
let output = question.get(isCorrect); // This retrieves one of the two phrases
console.log(output);
```

And what those three lines do can be shortened into just one line:

```
console.log(question.get(ans === question.get('correct')));
```

NB: using Maps in this way doesn't look right. You should really use an array for the questions, and plain object(s) for the other stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sure this is a horrible example of sets but is the one the lecturer is using. I just could not understand why the next lines of code were executed after my input. So if understand correct sets almost work like a loop? It iterates through the code; runs from top to bottom; has a value of true (depending on my input) and executes the code when the true key is found. I typed in another true set below the false set and saw that it ignores the first true key value and prints out the second true key's value.

Comment: There is no loop involved. The Map is a key/value [dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). You look up values by their keys. Such keys can also be `false`, `true`. So if you lookup a comparison (which results in `false` or `true`), you will get the corresponding value from that dictionary. There is no looping involved. Maps have *direct* access to whatever entry corresponds to the given key (at least that is how you could think of it -- the actual implementation involves hashing). `console.log` does the outputting of whatever is retrieved from the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for your patience trincot. I'm going to let this one go before I embarrass myself. This might just not be the best example for me and why it's confusing me so much.

Comment: I extended my answer a bit. Hope it makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: To elaborate: Maps are hashmaps. That means the key you're setting or looking up is run through a hash function -- something which generates a "fingerprint" for the key which can be used as an index pointing to where the value is stored. So when you do `map.get(true)`, the `true` is hashed, and that results in an index that points directly to the `Correct answer :D` string in memory. No loops needed, because it calculates the index directly from the key.

Comment: I woke up this morning and thought I will just go over some other examples and saw that I had some more replies. The combination of the edited answer and IceMetalPunk made me click so hard it was almost audible. Thank you both incredibly much. It was something small but you guys get what I wanted to know... Have a wonderful day.